# unit test case for super() in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a class as:

```
"""A"""

from clay import config
from datetime import timedelta
from <path> import B

EXECUTION_TIMEOUT = timedelta(minutes=30)

class A(B):
    """Crawler task for A"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialization."""
        super(A, self).__init__(execution_timeout=EXECUTION_TIMEOUT, *args, **kwargs)
```

I have a test file as :

```
"""Test class for A"""
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from doubles import allow
from mock import patch, MagicMock
from unittest import TestCase
import mock

from <path> import A


class JobInfoHandler:
    """Mock job info."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Init Method."""
        self.crawlerConfig = None
        pass


class TestA(TestCase):
    """Test class for A."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Create instance of class to test."""
        job_info_ob = JobInfoHandler()
        self.obj_a = A(owner='arahej', task_id='12',
                                              schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=60), job_info=job_info_ob)
```

When I run my test coverage command. The below line is not covered :

`super(A, self).__init__(execution_timeout=EXECUTION_TIMEOUT, *args, **kwargs)`

Can anyone help me with how to cover `super` here. I tried to mock or patch, but it didn't worked.

Comment: It's a consequence of the `A` class not being instantiated, which happens because there are no tests defined that actually require instantiating an `A` (in fact, no tests at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setUp()` method is only called when you write a test method as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp):

> **`setUp()`**
>
> Method called to prepare the test fixture. **This is called immediately before calling the test method**;...

```
class TestA(TestCase):
    """Test class for A."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Create instance of class to test."""
        print("Setting up testcase")
        job_info_ob = JobInfoHandler()
        self.obj_a = A(owner='arahej', task_id='12',
                                              schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=60), job_info=job_info_ob)
```

Here, you haven't defined any test method, thus `setUp()` would never be called, thus `A` would never be initialized which in turn would never call the initialization of parent `B` via `super().__init__()`.

```
$ coverage run -m unittest discover

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
$ coverage html
```

[image]

Adding a test method would now run `setUp()` which would initialize `A.__init__()` which in turn runs `B.__init__()` via `super()`.

```
class TestA(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def test_first(self):
        print("1st test method called")
        assert True
```

```
$ coverage run -m unittest discover
Setting up testcase
1st test method called
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
$ coverage html
```

[image]

Also, you mentioned about mocks/patches. You maybe misunderstanding what mocks/patches are for, because if you mock/patch the call to `super().__init__()` with a stub implementation, then it would not call the actual implementation and instead call the mocked/patched/stubbed version, which means it wouldn't solve your problem because the coverage to your actual implementation would still be missing as you replaced the actual call with a patched one. In other words, you're just making your problem worse by patching :)

Answer (score 1):

Try patching super:

```
from mock import patch


class B(object):

    def foo(self):
        print('foo from B')


class A(B):

    def foo(self):
        self.called_foo = True
        super(A, self).foo()


class TestA(object):

    @patch('%s.super' % __name__, create=True)
    def test_foo(self, super_func):
        A = A()
        A.foo()
        assert A.called_foo
        assert super_func.called
```